# Is there a difference in end result between merging branch A into B VS making a copy A', then merging B into A' and fast forwarding B to A'

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I have

```
main - 1 - 2 - 3 (A)
    \
     4 - 5 - 6 (B)
```

The remote repo's manager wants to merge `A` to `main` (ff) first, then merge `B` to `main`. Thus, he wants me to merge `A` into `B` first so there won't be issues later on:

```
              (A)
main - 1 - 2 - 3
    \           \ 
     4 - 5 - 6 - 7 (B)
```

```
           (A)
0 - 1 - 2 - 3
 \           \
  4 - 5 - 6 - 7 (B, main)
```

(an 8th commit isn't needed, right? Just ff `main` twice?)

#### My question is: would I get the exact same result (including git history or any other factors I don't know about) if I did this instead:

(I'll explain why I want to later on)

Create a copy of `A`, `A'`, then merge `B` into `A'`,

```
              (A)
main - 1 - 2 - 3 - 7 (A')
    \             /
     4 - 5 ----- 6
                (B)
```

Then fast-forward `B` into `A'`, deleting `A'` after,

```
              (A)
main - 1 - 2 - 3 - 7 (B)
    \             /
     4 - 5 ----- 6
```

Finally ff `main`.

```
           (A)             
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 7 (B, main)
 \             /           
  4 - 5 ----- 6
```

### Are there any reasons to avoid my second method?

---

Why I want to do this:

`B` contains some wrong changes from `main` that I don't want/is wrong. I don't remember what those changes are. If I merge `A` into `B`, these changes would still be there.

Therefore, I would like to manually vet through all changes made by `B`.

I could do an interactive rebase, but `B` has many commits. I don't want to go through all of them, and I also don't remember which commits introduced the wrong changes. Also, `A` made some renames that affected many files, which would cause conflicts I'd have to fix on every commit.

I also saw a three-way merge tool as option but I've never used that before and found this way easier.

Merging `B` into `A'` instead of `A` into `B` puts all the changes `B` has with respect to `A` in the working tree, allowing me to vet through all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't care about *branches*... here's the gist of it: to `git`, branches are *pointers* to commits. So, if you create a new branch over a commit, it's not like there's any change in history.... you are just creating *a new pointer to the same commit*.

Having said that, what you should do is track down where the broken change came from, then `git rebase -i` to edit the broken commit and remove the broken changes from that commit (or even remove the whole commit from history if needed).

Now, how can you easily know where the broken change came from? Normally, it's about running `git blame` or `git annotate` on the broken file to see where the broken lines where introduced. The other technique you can use is using `git bisect` which is a *very* handy tool that should be in the toolbox of developers who prides themselves of being such.

Comment: 1. I get that creating a new branch doesn't affect anything but I was more of asking whether merging B into A instead of A into B will cause any unwanted effects on the history.

2. are you talking about rebasing B onto A, or rebasing B onto itself to edit out the broken change, before merging A into B?

Comment: You set yourself on rthe branch that has a broken commit in it's history and let's say that the broken commit Is `x`. The Easy way to _"fix"_ the commit in history Is by rebasing: `git rebase -i x~` (careful to use the pigtail!!!). It will  open am editor with the listo of commits starting with the broken commit. Set that one to `edit` or `e`. Save and exit, git will stop right after applying the broken commit. Adjust the code so that it's _not_ broken... Add all changes, `git commit --amend --no-edit; git rebase --continue` and now the branch has been rewritten and the broken commit Is fixed

Comment: That should _not_ be done on branches/commits that have already been merged into branches that other people are already using.

Answer (score 1):

The file content will be the same (assuming the conflicts are resolved in the same way), but the order of the parents in the resulting merge commit will be different. This affects notations like `HEAD~3` and commands like `git log --first-parent`. It is usually best to merge a side/feature branch into a "main line" branch and not the other way around, so that the first parent will be the history of the main line.

This might also be a reason not to use a fast-forward merge into `main` to bring in a sequence of commits that ends with a merge commit.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645143/298656 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645133/298656 for more details.